# Python Lineair Interpolation with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to upsample and interpolate a not continuous sampling of a temp sensor by using the "read_csv" function of Pandas in Python.

Below my function used to upsample and interpolate:

```
def upsampled(filename):
    parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    series = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, 
    squeeze=True,date_parser=parser)
    upsampled = series.resample('1T')
    interpolated = upsampled.interpolate(method='linear')
    print(interpolated.head(100))
    interpolated.to_csv('test.csv',sep=';')
```

A part of  the content in the input .csv file with the uncontinuous sampling look like:

```
2020-03-04 04:49:08;327
2020-03-04 05:48:10;327
2020-03-04 05:58:10;327
2020-03-04 05:59:10;0
2020-03-04 06:11:10;9
2020-03-04 07:10:11;68
2020-03-04 08:09:12;127
2020-03-04 09:08:13;186
2020-03-04 10:07:14;246
```

The concent of the out file(test.cvs) in thecode with the continuous sampling + interpolation look like:

```
2020-03-04 05:46:00;326.82746249184606
2020-03-04 05:47:00;326.82713633398566
2020-03-04 05:48:00;326.82681017612526
2020-03-04 05:49:00;326.82648401826486
2020-03-04 05:50:00;326.8261578604044
2020-03-04 05:51:00;326.825831702544
2020-03-04 05:52:00;326.8255055446836
2020-03-04 05:53:00;326.8251793868232
2020-03-04 05:54:00;326.8248532289628
2020-03-04 05:55:00;326.8245270711024
2020-03-04 05:56:00;326.824200913242
2020-03-04 05:57:00;326.8238747553816
2020-03-04 05:58:00;326.8235485975212
2020-03-04 05:59:00;326.8232224396608
2020-03-04 06:00:00;326.8228962818004
2020-03-04 06:01:00;326.82257012394
2020-03-04 06:02:00;326.82224396607955
2020-03-04 06:03:00;326.82191780821915
2020-03-04 06:04:00;326.82159165035876
2020-03-04 06:05:00;326.82126549249836
2020-03-04 06:06:00;326.82093933463796
2020-03-04 06:07:00;326.82061317677756
2020-03-04 06:08:00;326.82028701891716
2020-03-04 06:09:00;326.81996086105676
2020-03-04 06:10:00;326.81963470319636
2020-03-04 06:11:00;326.81930854533596
2020-03-04 06:12:00;326.81898238747556
2020-03-04 06:13:00;326.81865622961516
```

What I don't understand: 
Why is there no interpolation for example between 2020-03-04 05:59:10 --> 2020-03-04 06:11:10? 
In the input file, the numbers are going from 0 to 9. It even erased the original 0 and 9 to write a 326.

For people who knows Pandas well, I would like to ask some help. I'm out of ideas for something that looked very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: before you make Pandas dataframe, you can give the columns a type in it's properties:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns =['StartTime',TagModel[0]['TagName'] ],dtype=float)
```

Adding this property leaves the dataframe as a dataframe and doesn't convert it to a series. Conclusion: **define the datatypes of your columns before starting to use the Pandas dataframe.**

Answer (score 0):

I get the distinct feeling that the linear interpolation is interpolating between the initial and end points of the file. Have you tried alternative methods of interpolation, such as 'time'?

Comment: Thank you. I should play more with the different "methods" within the "interpolate" function. But method "time" I tried and didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I first upsampled with a resolution of 1 second. Interpolation here seems to work perfect.
If my resolution needs to be one hour for example, I later downsample my 1 second resolution column to one hour by using this code:

```
def dataDownSampled(resultUpsampling1second,output):
    parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    series = pd.read_csv(resultUpsampling1second, sep = ';', header=0, parse_dates 
    [0], index_col=0,squeeze=True,date_parser=parser)
    downsampled = series.resample('1H')
    mean = downsampled.mean()
    mean.to_csv(output+'.csv',sep=';')
```

This did the job for me.